# How do you edit a Powershell script to continue on an error?

Tags: windows-server-2008, powershell

I modified this script(https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Create-HTML-Uptime-and-68e6acc0) to hit multiple servers, but it doesn't generate a report even if only one of the systems are down.  How do I modify the script to continue on errors and generate the report at the end?  The error is:

```
Get-WmiObject : The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA)
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\CheckDiskSpaceDomain\GetDiskDriveSpaceDomain.ps1:19 char:25
+      $os = Get-WmiObject <<<<  -class win32_OperatingSystem -cn $s
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [Get-WmiObject], COMException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : GetWMICOMException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetWmiObjectCommand

You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Users\user\Desktop\CheckDiskSpaceDomain\GetDiskDriveSpaceDomain.ps1:21 char:51
+        uptime = (get-date) - $os.converttodatetime <<<< ($os.lastbootuptime)}
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (converttodatetime:String) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvokeMethodOnNull
```

Comment: You need to spend some time learning how to catch exceptions.  http://blogs.technet.com/b/heyscriptingguy/archive/2010/03/11/hey-scripting-guy-march-11-2010.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have the issue when you run get-wmiObject, after that call just write

```
-ErrorAction "Resume"
```

Looks like the $OS is actually the null-value so you might want to do something like this that will know if $s is null and make a decision of what to do:

```
if ($OS -ne $null){ 
    $uptime = (get-date) - $os.converttodatetime 
    }
else {
    write-host " OS is null" 
     }
```

For more info on error handeling :

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kebab/archive/2013/06/09/an-introduction-to-error-handling-in-powershell.aspx

Comment: Thanks.

To clarify, the original script finishes even though it throws the errors, so I assumed something in the background was preventing it from outputting the report.

The report is still not generated even though I added -ErrorAction "Resume" (although I think it's "Continue") after the WMI call.

Any idea why the report wouldn't be generated for the servers that it can actually get the info from (while skipping the servers with the RPC errors)?

Answer (score 0):

Try using -erroraction silentlycontinue

Comment: A good answer should include a short explanation what that option does and why he should use it.